# Is there a way to access module.exports.myInstance in a function from other file?

Tags: node.js, async-await, module.exports

I want to access `module.exports.myInstance` in a function from other file which simply looks like this below.

```
// a.js
const func = async function () {
  ...
  module.exports.myInstance = ...;
}
func();

// b.js
const module = require("a.js").myInstance;
console.log(module);
```

I need to put `module.exports` inside of a function because I have something to work with await to get `myInstance`. I tried this and tested, but I've got `undefined` when `console.log(module)`. Is this not a possible format? If it is, what should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad pattern.. to let it works you should write:

```
// a.js
const func = async function () {
  module.exports.myInstance = 'hello'
}
func()

// b.js
require('./a.js') // trigger the async function

// wait the loading with nextTick or setTimeout (if the operation takes longer)
process.nextTick(() => {
  // you must re-run the require since the first execution returns undefined!
  console.log(require('./asd.js').myInstance)
})
```

As you see it is really fragile this code based on timing and execution order.

If you want a singleton you may write this:

```
// a.js
let cached
module.exports = async function () {
  if (cached) {
    return cached
  }
  cached = 'hello'
  return cached
}

// b.js
const factory = require('./a.js')

factory()
  .then(salut => { console.log(salut) })
```

Comment: I want to use factory as a global instance at b.js, which is like `factory.aaa.bbb()` or `factory.ccc.ddd()`. But by your example, it looks like I have to use `aaa.bbb()`, `ccc.ddd()` in `then()`.

Comment: Hmm and I've tested the first example you gave, it's result is same `undefined`.

Comment: I mispelled the file name `require('./asd.js')`. It works on node 12

Comment: It doesn't work on my side. I'm using node 12, too. `myInstance` at my case is `new Class()` at a.js. Is this could be why it doesn't work on my side? I'm confuesd.

Comment: To use `nextTick` you need to understand the [event loop queues](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) If you change the example you should use `setTimeout` instead since other code could change the execution order of the code